# NativeScript - Lag after Barcode Scan

Tags: nativescript, barcode-scanner, angular2-nativescript

I am using the nativescript barcode-scanner plugin for one of my Android platform projects. Problem we have is  once the the scan is done, we need the user to enter a some values to a text field. Problem is the the soft keyboard takes about 4 seconds to pop up. It seems the screen freezes for about 4 seconds soon after a scan. It the same if I have a button that needs pressing soon aftHave you come across this problem? If so do you know what the work around is? Below is type script code used to load scanner. Thanks any help you be great.

```
public scan() {
    console.log("On Scanning....");
    this.barcodeScanner.scan({
        formats: "QR_CODE, EAN_13",
        showFlipCameraButton: false,   
        preferFrontCamera: false,     
        showTorchButton: false,        
        beepOnScan: true,             
        torchOn: false,               
        resultDisplayDuration: 0
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(`Scanned: ${result.format} ${result.text}`);
        this.showResultView(result.text);
        }, (errorMessage) => {
            console.log("Error when scanning " + errorMessage);
        }
    );
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner

Comment: Which version of NativeScript you are using? Are you listening to app / activity's resume event to perform any operation in your app?

Comment: To be exact - 4.2.4

Comment: Well I am waiting for the scan to complete to do some actions. Apart from that not listening to anything else.